# Listview columns autosize to the longest item C++/CLI VS2012

Tags: c++, listview, visual-studio-2012

I am creating project in Visual Studio 2012 using C++/CLI . I have listview component in my project. I need to set autosize depending on content in this column. I have tried to set '-1' and '-2' but it doesn't work (columns become very wide ). Please help to solve this problem.
Thx in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 listView1->AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle::ColumnContent);
listView1->AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle::HeaderSize);
```